# GRAPH PageIterator returns same items multiple times

Tags: c#, pagination, microsoft-graph-api

I have the below method. The sample is published [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/paging?tabs=csharp).

While it is working, the callback is called correctly by each 2 items (Top(2)), the subsequent iterations contain overlapping person objects, and so, the dictionary will contain less unique items.

If I use a higher number than the total number of people in the folder, e.g. Top(100), then all Persons are delivered correctly.

My first thought was that it may failed because because of a missing order by clause, but it still keeps failing after adding it. I would appreciate any idea why it happens. Thanks.

```
public async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> LoadDisplayNames(string UserId)
{
    User GRAPHUser = await GetUser(UserId);
    Dictionary<string, string> ret = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    try
    {
        var Persons = await _service.Users[GRAPHUser.Id].People.Request()
            .Top(2)
            .OrderBy("displayName")
            .Select(e => new
            {
                e.ScoredEmailAddresses,
                e.DisplayName
            })
            .GetAsync();
        var pageIterator = PageIterator<Person>.CreatePageIterator(
                    _service,
                    Persons,
                    (p) =>
                    {
                        var HighestScoreAddress = p.ScoredEmailAddresses.OrderBy(a => a.RelevanceScore).FirstOrDefault();

                        if (HighestScoreAddress != null && !ret.ContainsKey(HighestScoreAddress.Address))
                        {
                            var email = HighestScoreAddress.Address.Replace("SMTP:", "");
                            ret.Add(email, $"{p.DisplayName} ({email})");
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                );
        await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(ex, ex.Message);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in Graph API. I've tried your query (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/people?$top=2&$select=displayName,scoredEmailAddresses&$orderBy=displayName) in Graph Explorer (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and the query returns still the same two records for each page.

Comment: @user2250152 thank you. So I guess I should open a bug report for MS Graph. Is it the correct place to do it (https://github.com/microsoft/GraphEngine/issues) ?

Comment: I'm aware that there is no official place where to report bug. The best place to report a bug should be Microsoft Q&A (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/index.html) under the tag microsoft-graph-people

Comment: Report URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/808248/graph-page-iterator-returns-same-items-multiple-ti.html